# How can we show 0 for the levels with 0 observation in a factor variable while using dcase

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(AEOUT = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "FATAL", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED", 
"NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", 
"NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED"), AEREL1S = c("UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", 
"UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", 
"UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "RELATED", 
"RELATED", "RELATED", "RELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED"
)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
> test<-df %>%dcast(.,AEOUT~AEREL1S)
Using 'AEREL1S' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Warning message:
In dcast(., AEOUT ~ AEREL1S) :
  The dcast generic in data.table has been passed a tbl_df and will attempt to redirect to the reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection yourself like reshape2::dcast(.). In the next version, this warning will become an error.
> dput(head(AE_OC, n=18))
structure(list(AEOUT = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "FATAL", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", 
"RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED", 
"NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", 
"NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED"), AEREL1S = c("UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", 
"UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", 
"UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "RELATED", 
"RELATED", "RELATED", "RELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED", "UNRELATED"
)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

For `AEOUT`, it has 6 levels. I wonder how should I show `0` for the levels that are not in the table?

```
AEOUT = factor(AEOUT, levels = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED","RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE", "RECOVERING/RESOLVING", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "FATAL", "UNKNOWN"))
```

I tried to summaries the data.Is it possible for me to keep the level even there is 0 obs?

My current codes are:

```
test<-df %>%dcast(.,AEOUT~AEREL1S)
```

and output looks like this:

[image]

And my ideal ouput should looks like this in this order:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table` after converting to `factor` with `levels`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(AEOUT = factor(AEOUT, 
      levels = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED","RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE", 
     "RECOVERING/RESOLVING", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED",
         "FATAL", "UNKNOWN"))) %>%
    table
```

-output

```
                              AEREL1S
AEOUT                              UNRELATED
  RECOVERED/RESOLVED                       4
  RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE         0
  RECOVERING/RESOLVING                     0
  NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED               3
  FATAL                                    1
  UNKNOWN                                  0
```

---

Or in the OP's code, specify `drop = FALSE` in `dcast`

```
df %>% 
     mutate(AEOUT = factor(AEOUT, levels = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED","RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE", 
     "RECOVERING/RESOLVING", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "FATAL", 
     "UNKNOWN"))) %>%
   data.table::dcast(AEOUT~AEREL1S, drop = FALSE)
```

-output

```
                              AEOUT UNRELATED
1               RECOVERED/RESOLVED         4
2 RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE         0
3             RECOVERING/RESOLVING         0
4       NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED         3
5                            FATAL         1
6                          UNKNOWN         0
```

Comment: For `drop`, I saw somebody using `.drop=F`  before. May I ask what `.` stand for? I tried that earlier and it won't run, so I thought drop can not be added to `dcast`.

Comment: @Stataq `.` prefix in arguments are commonly found in `tidyverse` package functions.  I guess it is their convention of specifying the arguments.  I am not sure why they do it.  May be they use it so that if there is a function of the same name, then it won't get masked

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dplyr::count` function with `.drop = FALSE` to do just what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(AEOUT = factor(AEOUT, levels = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED","RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE", "RECOVERING/RESOLVING", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "FATAL", "UNKNOWN"))) %>%
   count(AEOUT, .drop = FALSE)
## A tibble: 6 x 2
#  AEOUT                                n
#  <fct>                            <int>
#1 RECOVERED/RESOLVED                   4
#2 RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE     0
#3 RECOVERING/RESOLVING                 0
#4 NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED           3
#5 FATAL                                1
#6 UNKNOWN                              0
```

Comment: May I ask why we use `.drop` with `count`, but `drop` with `dcast`?

Comment: It's a good question. The development team behind the "tidyverse" set of packages, including `dplyr` seems to prefer arguments that start with `.` to differentiate the optional arguments from the main ones. There is some explanation in the [Tidyverse design guide](https://design.tidyverse.org/dots-prefix.html).

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `stack` + `table`

```
with(
  df,
  rev(
    stack(
      table(
        factor(AEOUT,
          levels = c("RECOVERED/RESOLVED", "RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE", "RECOVERING/RESOLVING", "NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED", "FATAL", "UNKNOWN")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

gives

```
                               ind values
1               RECOVERED/RESOLVED      4
2 RECOVERED/RESOLVED WITH SEQUELAE      0
3             RECOVERING/RESOLVING      0
4       NOT RECOVERED/NOT RESOLVED      3
5                            FATAL      1
6                          UNKNOWN      0
```